copy excel image using openpyxl. The source image was inserted using xlsxwriter
I want to copy an excel image from source sheet to target sheet.
At the beginning I inserted the photo using xlsxwriter in the code down below
def format_sheet_for_mapping_user_sector_location(
    writer: pd.ExcelWriter,
    sheet_params: dict,
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    column_headers: OrderedDict[str, MappingColumnHeader],
) -> Worksheet:
    image_path = sheet_params.get('image_path')
    if image_path:
        print(os.path.abspath(image_path))
        result = worksheet.insert_image('A1', os.path.abspath(image_path))
        print(result)

    return worksheet


and the function to copy is :
def copy_excel_images(source_sheet: Worksheet, target_sheet: Worksheet) -> None:
    """
    Copy all images from the source sheet to the target sheet.
    """
    for image in source_sheet._images:  # Access private `_images` attribute for all images
        new_image = Image(image.ref)  # Reuse the reference to the image
        new_image.anchor = image.anchor  # Maintain the same anchor position
        target_sheet.add_image(new_image)

At the end it doesn't copy the pictures knowing that I have the pictures inserted in the source file. Please Help !!

You're using private and undocumented attributes and asking for help?

This question is similar to: I need a way to copy images from one excel file to a new one in python. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
